# The side $AB$ of a triangle $ABC$ is a diameter of a circle

Tags: geometry

The side $AB$ of a triangle $ABC$ is a diameter of a circle which intersects $AC$ and $BC$ at $M,N$, respectively. If $AN=6,BM=8$ and $\measuredangle ACB=\varphi$, find the sides of the triangle.

[image]

When I was drawing the figure, I noted that $\measuredangle BAC>\measuredangle ABC$ for $AN<BM$. I don't know if this can be somewhat helpful, nor how to prove it.

$ABNM$ is actually an inscribed quadrilateral, so $\measuredangle BAN=\measuredangle BMN$ and $\measuredangle ABM=\measuredangle ANM$.

What else can I note? Thank you!

Comment: From where did you receive this question? Do you have the final answer?

Comment: @JitendraSingh, from a textbook of mine, but I don't have the answer.

Comment: Can you see $AC = 6 \csc \phi$? Similarly $BC$ can be found.

Comment: To find $AB$, apply cosine law or note $AB^2 = AN^2 + BN^2$

Comment: @MathLover, thank you for the response! I haven't seeen this trig function - cosecant, though...

Comment: Is trignommetry allowed Medi

Comment: @JitendraSingh, yes, it's. I just haven't studied cosecant.

Comment: Have you studied cos and sin? Even with that you can solve

Comment: No problem, $AN / AC = \sin \phi$ so $AC = AN / \sin\phi = 6 / \sin\phi$

Comment: @MathLover, thank you, I think I got it. For $AB=\dfrac{1}{\sin\varphi}\sqrt{100-96\cos\varphi}$?

Comment: Yes that is correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In triangle AMB:

$$\sin \widehat A=\frac 8{AB}$$

in triangle ABN:

$$\sin \widehat B=\frac 6{AB}$$

In triangle ABC:

$$\frac{AB}{\sin \phi}=\frac {AC}{\sin\widehat B}=\frac{BC}{\sin \widehat A} $$

$$\frac{AB}{\sin \phi}=\frac {AC}{\sin\widehat B=\frac 6{AB}}\Rightarrow AC=\frac6{\sin \phi}$$

$$\frac{AB}{\sin \phi}=\frac {BC}{\sin\widehat A=\frac 8{AB}}\Rightarrow BC=\frac8{\sin \phi}$$

$$AB^2=BC^2+AC^2-2 BC\cdot AC \cos \phi$$

$$AB^2=\frac{6^2}{\sin^2\phi}+\frac{8^2}{\sin^2\phi}-2\frac {6\times 8}{\sin^2\phi}\cos \phi$$

$$\Rightarrow AB=\frac1{sin\phi}\sqrt{100-96\cos \phi}$$